# Unscale predictions back to original form

Tags: neural-network, time-series, regression, prediction, scaling

This is a regression problem.

The shape of my training is: (417, 5) and the test data shape is: (105, 5). I do scaling for both using the following code:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
#Scale train
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
train_df = scaler.fit_transform(train_df)
train_df = pd.DataFrame(train_df)

#Scale test
test_df = scaler.fit_transform(test_df)
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_df)
```

First four rows of training data after scaling look like below:

[image]

while '4' is the dependent variable and the rest are independent variables.

After training using deep neural network, I get predictions in scaled form. I try to unscale predictions using the following code:

```
scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred_dnn)
```

while predictions are stored in  `y_pred_dnn`

But I get the following error:

ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (105,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (105,5)

How do I debug the problem?

Thanks

Comment: looks like your y_pred_dnn variable has 5 dimensions instead of one. can you share where that variable is coming from?

Comment: @AleixCC:     No y_pred_dnn has only one dimension, the original dataset has 5 dimensions.

Comment: @AleixCC:    Even if I keep predictions in dataframe using code:  `df_dnn = pd.DataFrame(data = y_pred_dnn)`, when I find it shape using   `df_dnn.shape`, I get output as:    (105, 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can solve this by separating out y before scaling. You dont need to scale y for prediction. So try:

```
y_train, y_test = train_df.iloc[:, 4], test_df.iloc[:, 4]
X_train, X_test = train_df.iloc[:, 1:4], test_df.iloc[:, 1:4]
```

After this you do te scaling on X part only and you wont need any inverse scaling

Comment: Thanks, that is a great idea not to scale dependent variable.

Comment: while this is doable, the MAE for keras models that have all data scaled is much better than for features only. Really, no other way to solve this?